# TypeError: compiler.getInfrastructureLogger is not a function at CLIPlugin.apply

Tags: webpack

I am having a hard time setting up my webpack-babel config for my react-typescript project.

When I try to build with the command `rm -rf ./dist && webpack --mode production` it throws an error like this:

```bsh
[webpack-cli] TypeError: compiler.getInfrastructureLogger is not a function
    at CLIPlugin.apply (/Users/VIU/Projects/prueba-axpe-consulting-2/my-app/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/plugins/CLIPlugin.js:116:32)
    at WebpackCLI.webpack (/Users/VIU/Projects/prueba-axpe-consulting-2/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:37:12)
    at WebpackCLI.createCompiler (/Users/VIU/Projects/prueba-axpe-consulting-2/my-app/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:2053:29)
    at async WebpackCLI.buildCommand (/Users/VIU/Projects/prueba-axpe-consulting-2/my-app/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:2173:20)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/Users/VIU/Projects/prueba-axpe-consulting-2/my-app/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:850:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/Users/VIU/Projects/prueba-axpe-consulting-2/my-app/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1495:13)
```

my `webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].js',
        publicPath: ''
    }
};
```

Versions:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "source-map-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "4.19.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2"
  }
```

I am using `yarn`. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with webpack-cli@^4.7.2. I didn't have time to research the exact cause or fix. Instead, I searched for "getInfrastructureLogger" in the code, and replaced it with this.

```
this.logger = console; // compiler.getInfrastructureLogger("webpack-cli");
```

Any object that defines a log function should work. I know it's a hack, but it got me unblocked until I can find a more comprehensive solution.

Answer (score 1):

It works by reinstalling Webpack Dev Server to the version @2.5.1

```
 yarn add webpack-dev-server@2.5.1
```